# How to use use php preg_split with an html string

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to parse a badly formed html table:

A couple of lines of this are:

```
  Food:</b> Yes<b><br>
  Pool: </b>Beach<b></b><b><br>
  Centre:</b> Yes<b><br>
```

After spending a lot of time on this with Xpath, I think it is probably better to split the above text into lines use `preg_split` and parse from there.

The pattern I think would work uses:

```
<\b><\br>*: <\b>
```

my code is as follows:

```
$pattern='</b></br>*:</b>';           
$pattern=preg_quote($pattern,'#');
$chars = preg_split($pattern, $output);
print_r($chars);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Regular expressions cannot properly handle HTML in general, and while in some cases you can make assumptions that will allow regex to handle a specific HTML string, it is [strongly recommended against](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Just note that in the "pattern I think would work" you are using a backslash, which must be escaped with another backslash when used in a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern='</b></br>*:</b>';           
$pattern=preg_quote($pattern,'#');
$chars = preg_split('#'.$pattern.'#', $output);
print_r($chars);
```

The `preg_quote` function just makes it safely escaped, it doesn't actually add the delimiters for you.

As other people will surely point out, using regular expressions is not a good way to parse HTML :)

Your regular expression is also not going to match what you hope. Here's a version that will probably work for your input:

```
$in = " Pool: </b>Beach<b></b><b><br>";
$out = explode(':', strip_tags($in));
$key = trim($out[0]);
$value = trim($out[1]);
echo "$key = $value\n";
```

This removes all the HTML, then splits on the colon, and then removes any surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Just modified the explode to use `':'` instead of `'!:!'` - the latter was left over cruft in the translation from `preg_quote()`

Comment: Thanks Cal, Also just wanted to let you know that I ended up using a combination of xpath and http://www.bitrepository.com/web-programming/php/extracting-content-between-two-delimiters.html to solve this. Thank you - Bill

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern needs to start and end with a delimiter; looks like you're using `#` if I'm reading this correctly, so you should have `$pattern = '#</b></br>.*:</b>#';`.

Also, you're mixing things up; `*` is not a simple wildcard in regex. If you mean "any number of any characters," the pattern you need is `.*`. I've included this above.

Comment: Guys,Thanks for your help. Cal you were right that the regex would not work correctly. Unfortunately your approach doesn't work either because or the irregular nature of the table's text. I'm going back to xpath to try a different tack. BTW what does '!:!' in explode above do? I used ':' instead - Bill

Comment: @user61629: You commented on my answer, not Cal's. You need to comment on his so he'll get a little note saying that you did.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you put all comments at the end, I've done it now.